# PHP - return confirm within PHP issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

could somebody please help me with the below:

```
echo ('<a href="assign.php?id=' . $id . '" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?');" style="text-decoration: none"><font color="FFFFFF"><b>Click here to claim ticket</b></font></a>');
```

I know there is an issue with some " ' " but can't figure this out. I am getting a syntax error just before the 'Are'. The line of code was working as expected before I added the:

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?');"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?\')`

Comment: This is one of those cases where you're better of interpolating php code into your HTML instead of the other way around. `<a href="assign.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">...</a>`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the same quotes you opened the string with inside the string itself, you should escape it.
For instance:

```
$var = 'Hello, let's go!';
echo $var;
```

This code will throw a parse error because this is how PHP sees the code:

1. ) New variable $var.
2. ) Is a string, declared using single quotes `'`.
3. ) After the opening quote we have 'Hello, let'
4. ) Now PHP expects some kind of valid code operators, like `.`, and next string or `;`, but it gets some characters, which are treated as instructions rather than strings because they are outside the quotes, and
5. ) PHP throws a parse error.

To fix this, you can use the backslash `\` a.k.a  'escaping' character.
For example, to fix your problem:

```
echo 
('<a href="assign.php?id=' . $id . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?\');" style="text-decoration: none"><font color="FFFFFF"><b>Click here to claim ticket</b></font></a>');
```

See the baskslashes `\` surrounding the single quotes inside the confirm JavaScript function? This tells PHP to treat these quotes as normal characters instead of string start/end declarations. Same thing works for reversal when you use double quotes as string declarators.
 For example, when you want to show the actual representation of `$` or any characters that have special meaning in a double quoted string, which allows direct insertion of variables (and some other's, like class properties) values you would use the escaping character. 
For example:

```
$apples = 12;
$talk = "I have $apples \$apples. Thanks, now have a backlash! \\!";
echo $talk;
```

This will output `I have 12 $apples. Thanks, now have a backslash! \!`
Now, you are not actually required to escape the escaping character (it will show just as well if it does't have anything to escape after it).
Read this: [PHP Manual - About Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the nested `'` by doing `\'`

```
echo ('<a href="assign.php?id=' . $id . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?\');" style="text-decoration: none"><font color="FFFFFF"><b>Click here to claim ticket</b></font></a>');
```

Note that all the stuff inside the single quotes is considered as string by the PHP interpreter.

**Docs:** [PHP: Variables - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php)

Comment: Thanks! Knew it was something simple. Still new to all this!

Comment: @pauloc1995 You're welcome! Please upvote and mark this answer as accepted if it helped you and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can also switch your single quotes on the edges of your echo statement with regular quotes, which will allow you to insert the `$id` variable easier. Then, you just have to escape the quotes around your JavaScript in `onClick` and switch all the other quotes to single quotes.

```
echo "<a href='assign.php?id=$id' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?');\" style='text-decoration: none'><font color='FFFFFF'><b>Click here to claim ticket</b></font></a>";
```

However, there is a better way.

### Interpolate PHP into HTML

(Instead of HTML into PHP)

The best way to do this is to write HTML as HTML, and interpolate PHP variables into the HTML. This is best practice as it allows syntax highlighting in IDE's, and looks much cleaner/easier to read.

Just write the entire element as HTML, and then echo the `$id` variable inside the HTML (instead of writing all of the HTML in a PHP echo statement).

```
<a href="assign.php?id=<?=$id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to claim this ticket?');" style="text-decoration: none">
    <font color="FFFFFF">
        <b>
            Click here to claim ticket
        </b>
    </font>
</a>
```

With this method, you don't have to worry about escaping quotes, and it will allow you to use regular quotes throughout your entire element.